# Identify the data type of a class member

Tags: c++

I'm navigating thru class members and I'm trying to find out which data type they are.

```
class ZObject
{
public:
    int a; //0x00
    bool b; //0x01
    DWORD c; //0x02
    DWORD d; //0x03
    D3DXVECTOR3 e; //0x04
};
DWORD offset = 0x01;
void PrintDataType( DWORD* pointertozobject )
{
  printf(  typeid(*(pointertozobject +offset)).name() );
}
```

I keep increasing `offset`by `+=0x01`, for each call I do to this function, but it always prints `unsigned long`which is the type of `pointertozobject`, how can I print the datatype of the class member in that offset? (It doesn't needs to be the pointer, I just need to identify it)

Comment: Well, `pointertozobject` points to an array of `DWORD`s (`unsigned long`). What else would you expect it to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't have that kind of type reflection.  As a comment states, the *type* of your expression is `DWORD` so that is the answer you get.  The address is meaningless.

In order to find type from structure offset you'd have to construct the table yourself, using `offsetOf()` plus `typeid()` to manually note the type of each member and its offset.  Then you could search the table for the desired offset and find the type.

Comment: Thanks, `offsetOf` helped quite a bit also I didn't know you could get it by debugging and see the offset getting moved into the register